Declaration of a static variable followed by redeclaration as extern and vice versa
#include <stdio.h>
static int a;
extern int a;
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}

This C code compiles and runs fine.

#include <stdio.h>
extern int a;
static int a;

int main()
{ //static int a;
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}

But this fails to compile and says:
error: static declaration of ‘a’ follows non-static declaration
   11 | static int a;
      |            ^
main.c:10:12: note: previous declaration of ‘a’ with type ‘int’
   10 | extern int a;


#include <stdio.h>

static int a=9;
int  a;
int main()

{ //static int a;

    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}

This code also gives an error:
error: non-static declaration of ‘a’ follows static declaration
   14 |   int  a;
note: previous definition of ‘a’ with type ‘int’
   11 | static int a=9;



#include <stdio.h>
 
static int a;
int  a;

int main()
{ 
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;

Compilation error:
 error: non-static declaration of ‘a’ follows static declaration
   14 |   int  a;
      |        ^
main.c:11:12: note: previous definition of ‘a’ with type ‘int’
   11 | static int a=9;
      |            ^


Please give why I am not getting any error when I am redeclaring with keyword extern and getting error when not using extern if the previous declaration is static.
By default file scope variables are treated as extern but why the error is occurring in the latter cases?
Please suggest according to C standards not machine dependent features.
What am I missing here ?

Can you justify why you want to write code like this? You cannot "go out on the town" and "stay at home" at exactly the same time, can you? Suggest you focus on learning to write good code instead of trying to find out why nonsensical code does not work...

yes you are right feric oxide.but if i don't learn why thiese things happen i may commit mistakes in future. And the next thing is that in India for engineering grads there is an exam called GATE for doing masters. In cs paper they ask such questions whether such a code will compile or not ,what will be output  like that.

Quite simply, brush up on what static means when defining a variable. Realise that extern is simply a promise (a declaration) to the compiler that the linker WILL find a GLOBAL variable in another object file that matches this variable's name and datatype. In this context, static means "only referenced in this translation unit". The correct answer to a question presenting code such as you've asked about is, "This code expresses garbage. Modifiers static and extern should never be simultaneously used in relation to the same variable. I'm feeling sick just seeing this."

Look! int main( void ) { 42; 128; 27;;;; 35; return 0; } This compiles to an executable! Is it sensible? There are unlimited ways to write bad code. You'll never be able to study all of them. Invest your time on understanding what is hard enough - how to think in productive directions. With that approach, code that smells bad to you is, very likely, to BE bad...

@SwastikSanyal there is an exam called GATE for doing masters. In cs paper they ask such questions whether such a code will compile or not  Ouch.  Do they ask civil engineers to memorize what the characteristics of concrete would be if a ton of fresh cow manure is added to the mix?  "Fails to compile" is not a required behavior from a C implementation.

In particular, per footnote 9:  "The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program."  Strictly speaking, "does not compile" can not be a correct answer per the C standard on any question even given the worst possible C code.  That's repeated in draft C23

I see . i haven't any idea of these information. Thank you for suggesting but it is what it is .


Please give why I am not getting any error when i am redeclaring with keyword extern

The n1570 draft standard describes (and allows) it in section 6.2.2 Linkage of identifiers

For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a
prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or
external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the
linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

So for this code
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a;   // external linkage

we have external linkage.
But for this code
#include <stdio.h>
static int a;   // internal linkage
extern int a;   // internal linkage

we have internal linkage.
In the same section the standard also says:

If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external
linkage, the behavior is undefined.

So for this code
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a;   // external linkage
static int a;   // internal linkage

we have a conflict.
In section 6.9.2 the standard has this example:
int i1 = 1;        // definition, external linkage
static int i2 = 2; // definition, internal linkage
extern int i3 = 3; // definition, external linkage
int i4;            // tentative definition, external linkage
static int i5;     // tentative definition, internal linkage
int i1;            // valid tentative definition, refers to previous
int i2;            // 6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
int i3;            // valid tentative definition, refers to previous
int i4;            // valid tentative definition, refers to previous
int i5;            // 6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
extern int i1;     // refers to previous, whose linkage is external
extern int i2;     // refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
extern int i3;     // refers to previous, whose linkage is external
extern int i4;     // refers to previous, whose linkage is external
extern int i5;     // refers to previous, whose linkage is internal

Notice for instance the int i5; example.

Thank you for your clarification. Can you please put some light on translation unit and the 3rd and 4 th code .

@SwastikSanyal Well, it's not fully correct but you can think of a "translation unit" as being a single C source file. There is a bit more to it than that but it's too much to describe in a comment. For the correct description read section 5.1.1.1 of N1570

@SwastikSanyal Your 3rd and 4th code examples are identical to i2 and i5 in the example I posted.

@SupportUkraine And!... some of these meanings change if the statement appears inside the body of a function! :-)

@SwastikSanyal Google what is meant by tenative definition in c language... THIS is an example of the terminology you need to grapple with; not one specific pairing of two language elements...

@Fe2O3 yep.... but a single answer can't cover the whole language... unless we copy-paste the whole standard... but that seems a bad idea :-)

Thank you so much Support Ukraine and Ferric oxide for such valuable information
